# Inkscape pixels VS Xcode 6 pixels

Tags: ios, xcode, inkscape

[Pixels in Inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMS9V.png)

[Pixels in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4aN3.png)

My question is prettty simple: what are default pixels image in Xcode 6 ?

I just want the know the exact proportions on Inkscape so I can put that same pixels in Xcode.

Whatever I try I can't get the solution, I googled the default DPI for iOS but when I enter those they still dont match.

Comment: The dpi will vary according to the device. I think you need to check out the resolutions here and generate assets in 1x, 2x, 3x for your project. Check this link - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Why is this tagged `d`?

Comment: those buttons are all 1x....do you thinki should put them on 3x and then will be better ? Or I shoul put images for 1x and 2x and 3x 
Thank you for the link btw 

@Bauss dunno...mistake i guess